# Java Abstract Class - What is going on here?

Tags: java, class, canvas, abstract, bufferstrategy

I've been searching/reading docs from Oracle for about 2 hours, and I'm pretty stumped. I had thought I understood what an abstract class was, and how it was used (at a basic level, at least). I'm still fairly new to all this, so bear with me please.

As I understand it, an abstract class cannot be instantiated, and instead requires a subclass to implement any part of it. The classes I was looking at, trying to dissect and understand, were BufferStrategy and Canvas, as well as how they work together. I'm not using these classes in a project, more or less just want to understand how they work.

So, let's say I have my Canvas and am creating a BufferStrategy for it:

```
BufferStrategy bs;
Canvas c;
c = new Canvas();
c.createBufferStrategy(2);
bs = c.getBufferStrategy();
```

The docs say ".getBufferStrategy()" returns the BufferStrategy currently being used in Canvas. It's obviously not returning an *instance* of BufferStrategy, so what exactly is it returning, and *how* is it being stored in "bs"? Also, what would I even refer to "bs" as, when "canvas" would be: "an instance of Canvas"?

I noticed the only subclasses of BufferStrategy, "Component.BltBufferStrategy & Component.FlipBufferStrategy", which I as far as I can tell are nested in Component, and thus shared with Canvas. But I fail to see anywhere that it comes into play.

I hope all this made sense. I apologize if this is a simple basic level question I should know by now, but it's the first thing in the last year that has actually stumped me; probably because I didn't understand certain concepts as well as I had thought. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that your question is really about "how do references (or maybe variables) work in Java?"?

Comment: If BltBufferStrategy extends BufferStrategy so you can assign it to a BufferStrategy reference, in this case only methods from the BufferStrategy will be available to call. If you want to call a method that is specific for BltBufferStrategy then you need to cast the object to a reference of its type.

Comment: Oh man. @Marcos Vasconcelos  Thanks for putting me back on the right track. Immediately after reading your replies, it clicked.  I think I should've just gotten up from my desk for a bit, 'cause I had gotten in a rut, and started thinking about it in the wrong way. Thank you both!